# Getting an error in passing a variable through routes to controller in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-routing

In app\routes.php
    `Route::get('author/(:any)',array('as'=>'author','uses'=>'AuthorsController@get_view'));`

In app\controllers\AuthorsController.php

```
<?php
class AuthorsController extends BaseController {
public $restful=true;

 public function get_view($id){
  return View::make('authors.view')
->with('title','Author View Page')
->with('author',Author::find($id));
 }

 }
```

In views\authors\view.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <title> {{ $title }}</title> </head>
<body>
<h1> {{$author->name}}</h1>
<p> {{ $author->bio}}  </p>
<p><small>{{$author->updated_at}} <small></p>
</body>
</html>
```

In a database there is a table named authors containing columns "id", "name", "bio","created_at","updated_at".
Also explain me the exact use of 'as'=>'authors' in the above code

Comment: Are you using Laravel 3?

Comment: I am using laravel 4.2

Comment: Are you sure? In Laravel 4.2 your route would look like this: `Route::get('author/{id}', ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route should be:

```
Route::get('author/{id}', array('as'=>'author', 'uses'=>'AuthorsController@get_view'));
```

Comment: can u please explain me the exact use of 'as'=>'author' in the above code

Comment: the 'as'=>'author' allows you to give the route a name.  Where as normally the resourced routes have dot notation names, this will allow you to specify a named route to access.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 1):

Your route is using old style syntax.  In 4.2 use `{}` in URIs to indicate a variable.

```
Route::get('author/{id}', array('as' => 'author', 'uses' => 'AuthorsController@get_view'));
```